# Python JsonDecoder analogue in Kotlin/JVM

Tags: java, python, json, kotlin, parsing

In `python json` module we have [JsonDecoder::raw_decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) method.

> Decode a JSON document from s (a str beginning with a JSON document)
> and return a 2-tuple of the Python representation and the index in s
> where the document ended.
>
> This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may have
> extraneous data at the end.

<sub>from python docs</sub>

I need equivalent to this method in Kotlin/JVM

---

I have idea:

Independently calculate the end of the json in a string using brace balancing, and then call the parser for the substring with the found indexes. It may work, but looks inefficient

Maybe there is a better solution?

---

P.S
The input string can be text and json mixed together. For example,

`{json} some text {more json} {and more json} and now some text`

---

I followed Adam's advice, but it doesn't do exactly what I need.

I wanted to do this:

1. Read from the stream until we find the `{` or `[`
2. Parsing the JSON while it is available (until the next part of the plain text)
3. Repeat from step 1

**But** `JsonFactory.createParser(InputStream)` reads about 8000 characters from the stream, because of this I can't skip the text without json and I am getting an exception.

Can I configure it so that it only reads the required minimum from the InputStream?

Comment: Something like [`JsonParser.readValueAsTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#readValueAsTree--) might be useful. If you created it via [`JsonFactory.createParser(InputStream)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html#createParser-java.io.InputStream-) you would still have the stream to continue manipulating.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I need a little bit help, see updated question please

Comment: You can implement step 1 yourself, then in step 2 pass the input stream at the correct location to the JsonFactory (I've not used JsonParser myself, I just looked it up for you). [PushbackInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) might be good for putting the first token back for the parser. Starting to get complicated...

Comment: @AdamMillerchip  That's exactly what I did. I implemented the first step, and read the first part of the Json. But, as you could see in the example from the question, the structure can be like `{json} some text {more json} {and more json} and now some plain text`. My ultimate goal is extract json embedded in the JS code